# Random Numbers doesnot append in textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello this is something new i discovered today i cant append the Other strings when creating random characters string of 20 chars

here is my code

```
Const llen As Integer = 20 ' total 20 chars

Dim cp() As Integer = {48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90}
Dim ch As Integer
Dim r As System.Random = New System.Random()

Dim rndm() As Char = New Char(llen) {}

For i As Integer = 0 To llen - 1
    ch = cp(r.Next(0, cp.Length))
    rndm(i) = Chr(ch)
Next

Dim randchars As String = rndm

Dim first As String = "CUSTOM1"

Dim second As String = "CUSTOM2"

Textbox1.Text = first & randchars & second
```

now the output doesnot append second string after those random chars if i take this way

Textbox1.Text = randchars & second & first

output is only randchars not first and second
but if i append randchars after both strings it appends what can be the problem ?

Comment: `rndm()` ends with an uninitialized element because `Dim rndm() As Char = New Char(llen) {}` creates an array with 21 elements.  I cant quite follow what the problem is, but a Null element would signal end of string.

Comment: That's correct, but the problem is also in _llen-1_ It should be _rndm.Length - 1_

Comment: @Plutonix ...and end of string makes textboxes not render the rest of the string.

Comment: so what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: To fix it you gotta use (just like Steve said) `Dim rndm() As Char = New Char(llen - 1) {}`. When declaring arrays you should always set the length to one less than what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

okay guys this can be fixed taking String Builder on place of Dim rndm() As Char = New Char(llen) {} and then appending to string builder and at the end stringbuilder.tostring

Comment: And all you missed in your initial code was three characters: `- 1`.